# Validation does not work on dynamically loaded form via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In MVC 3.0 and where and when I disabled unobtrusive javascript :

**`<key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />`**

If I load a form through jQuery ajax, the validation does not work! Indeed the following code returns null :

```
alert(Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm($(this).closest('form')[0]));
```

I know the solution when  unobtrusive is enabled (through calling $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(id); ) 
but when it is disabled what should I do??

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have called `Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load();` as well.

Let's take an example.

View model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

View (`Index.cshtml`):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('@Url.Action("create")', function (result) {
        $('#foo').html(result);

        // That's the important bit that you were probably missing
        Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load();

        $('form').submit(function () {
            if (Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm(this).validate('submit').length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="foo"></div>
```

Partial containing the form that is dynamically loaded (`Create.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel

@{Html.EnableClientValidation(true);}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Remark: obviously this answer is valid only if you want to use the totally obsolete `Microsoft*.js` scripts instead of the recommended jQuery unobtrusive and jQuery validate plugins. So it is valid only if you set `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/>` in your web.config.

Comment: I added Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load(); to the page and it runs without any errors but nothing changed! It returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined" when reaches Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm(this)

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej, I don't know you are not showing your code so it's difficult to diagnoze the problem. I have provided you a full working example.

Comment: maybe the problem is because of another form that I have in "index.cshtml" page. Anyway, I undrestood that I can enable unobtrusive for a single page by calling Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true) ! So I changed my strategy to use unobtrusive javascript JUST for the current page!...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to turn off validation only to do it by hand.
Anyway, your problem is that when you turn off unobtrusive validation the asp.net helpers don't output the data- attributes that are used by the validation functions.

My suggestion would be to leave `<key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />` and un-register the jQuery events.

Comment: becuase of some problems I cannot turn on the unobtrusive. So what is the solution without it?

Comment: write your own, from scratch.